# How to accept bitcoin and giving each user a unique address amd automatic withdrawal

Tags: exchanges, payment, full-node, ripple-gateways

I want to create a website when users on singing up will get a unique address and after getting my websites service,they can withdrawal the money also automatically.
Is that bitcoin integration free ? Plz help i am noobie to this.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand your question. Please try and be more precise! What is it exactly that you want to do? Accept bitcoin for services? Or send people bitcoin? Both? What does this have to do with ripple-gateways or exchanges?

Comment: Means i want a website where people on signing up will get a unique address. And on certain game or competition they will either loose or win bitcoin. And they can withdraw their amount automatically. Is bitcoin integration free and what is meant by running full node etc. Blah blah blah

Comment: There are many things hidden in that question of yours. It's not really a question at all, but more of a plea that says something like 'I want to create some website business that uses bitcoin. Can someone please do my work for me, explain bitcoin to me and figure out how it fits into my (secret or unknown) business idea?'. The 'blah blah blah' is a good indicator here.

Comment: I would advise you to first find out more concrete questions, like for example "what is meant by running a full node?". That's a good question. You will find great answers already present, like this one: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48436/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-term-full-node

Comment: Once you have worked through the answers and links provided there, new questions will arise, and you can repeat the process. This in turn will lead to more clarity about how bitcoin works and what it can or cannot do for your business idea. Notice that is work that needs to be done by yourself. Asking others to do it for you is lazy and probably won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds that right way for you would be to run Bitcoin Core (full node) and develop your own deposit / withdrawal system from scratch. Relying on third party APIs has potential problems with reliablity, security and user's privacy.

Some notes:

- If you plan that single user can deposit BTC multiple times, best practice is to change deposit address with each new deposit for the user. Address generation is free. This helps both user's and overall Bitcoin privacy, without downsides from your side (apart from some little more effort in coding solution).
- When user withdraw their BTC, it is best practice to batch their transactions together, it will take less space in blockchain and you will save on transaction fees. Basically, there is no point in sending out another transaction, before previous one is confirmed, in that time you should just add withdrawals into queue and then combine them together in a single withdrawal transaction. Final transaction confirmation time 99% cases will be the same, but it will be cheaper.

This is a good book if you want to understand how Bitcoin works from technical side - https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook.

Answer (score 0):

You could use online providers such as:

- https://www.blockchain.com/api
- https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/

Or install [Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/) to run a full node and use RPC APIs